# Prevent Duplicate Google Form Submissions

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I just built a Google Form for a registration system. I want to prevent duplicate submissions in the form but I don't want to use the option of "Only allow one response per person(Requires Login)" mainly because of the reason that it required login to a Google Account and I don't want that. I hope there could be a solution for the same using Google Apps Script but I am not much familiar with it. Hope if someone can help me out.

Comment: The script would need to check for some kind of unique information that was collected from that user.  Does the user give a name, or some kind of unique information that could be checked, to determine if that person had already made a response.  And what is the column Title or column letter?

Comment: There is an unique column of the Email. The column title is "Email".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it'll be much easier to detect & remove duplicates in the results sheet, adding a column or using conditional formatting with a custom LOOKUP or MATCH formula to see if the same value is found in earlier rows/records.

At the moment, LOOKUP is giving me spurious results. MATCH works fine. I sometimes get very delayed results from conditional formatting, so I'd go for a new column with the formula (assuming email is in column A, and you're entering the formula in cell B2)

= NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)))

This will return TRUE for duplicates.